# Are there varying degrees of engine misfire?

Tags: engine, misfire

My fault codes indicate engine misfires on 2 (of 6) cylinders but I don't hear or feel any problems at all in the engine or exhaust. When I've observed engine misfires before, it was pretty obvious.

I'm wondering if there could somehow be misfires that aren't as bad as others?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, misfires vary in their severity.

However, it is worth mentioning that your reader may be displaying old codes, or codes which were triggered by abnormal engine activity that is no longer present.

For example, if the vehicle were filled up with a bad batch of fuel that had water it, it could temporarily cause misfires. The fault codes for misfires would persist even though normal service resumes once the bad batch of fuel is spent.

Comment: I figured they were old codes, but I didn't want to clutter the post with a bunch of follow on questions. Good answer